# How to create a Uml Diagram with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, architecture, visual-studio-2013, uml, diagram

I would like to make a UML flow diagram and I currently have Visual studio 2013 however I cannot find a way to begin creating a UML Diagram i.e. either the project to add or the item.

I cannot find the 'Architecture Menu' and there doesnt seem to be a way to add it.
[image]

Any Ideas on what I'm missing / Doing wrong?

This is the type of diagram I would like to create:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You require the Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate SKU to access the modeling features. To check which version of Visual Studio you have click on `Help > About Microsoft Visual Studio`.

You can compare the features available across various SKUs here: http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs

Comment: Dam I'm running professional :/ Thanks for the assist